# Django filtering ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is view:

```
def post(self, request):
    author_request = request.data.get("author")
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(author=author_request)
    serializer = BookSerializer(queryset, None)
    return Response(serializer.data, HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.full_name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Author'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Authors'
```

So, when i try to filter the book by author i get the error. The error tells me that the POST data that i entered which is "Aleksa Petrovic" a name of a author that exists in the database is not an UUID. So when i filter it, it filters by UUID and i want it to filter by "full_name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Book.objects.filter(author__full_name=name_of_author)
```

One can use double underscores (`__`) to look "*through*" relations.

The view thus looks like:

```
def post(self, request):
    author_request = request.data.get('author')
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(author__full_name=author_request)
    serializer = BookSerializer(queryset, None)
    return Response(serializer.data, HTTP_200_OK)
```

Typically searches with a filter are *not* handled by a POST request, but by a GET request, since a GET request is supposed to *retrieve* data from the web server.

Comment: The double underscores can also be though of as the period (`.`) in Python

Comment: It works, thank you! btw can that "__" after the "author" which is a class or the author field? Can it be used only on FreignKey

Comment: @Arandomcoder: not entirely, since it uses the `related_query_name`, whereas if one would use a dot, it would be the `related_name`. If `related_query_name` is not specified, but `related_name` is, then it is the same as the `related_name`. Furthermore one can make a chain of underscores, whereas if we would work with someobject.somem2mfield.someotherfield` will not work.

Comment: @Aleksa: you can use it to filter on the fields of the `author` of the `Book`. It can follow `ForeignKey`s, `OneToOneField`, and `ManyToManyField`s all in two directions. Furthermore it is also used for field lookups.

Comment: Damn, you are good at this. Can i add you on discord if you have it. Im doing a project rn and i might have some more questions and here i can only ask every 90min